# service that will run and stop automatically in background

Tags: android, service

need a service that will run in background and it will awake after 30-120 seconds and find the location where the device is,then send the location to the data center and go to sleep.Again 30-120 seconds later service awake and determine location and go to sleep. I can start and stop the service manually.But i need to start(between 30 to 120 sec) and stop the service automatically.I can not remain the service live cause it will drain the battery.

```
So,My question is how can i start and stop the service automatically?
```

Thanks advance for any suggestion.

My code is

```
public class Service extends Activity {
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        Button stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stopButton);

        start.setOnClickListener(startListener);
        stop.setOnClickListener(stopListener);

   }

private OnClickListener startListener = new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v){
    startService(new Intent(Service.this,SimpleService.class));
}
```

};

```
private OnClickListener stopListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v){
        stopService(new Intent(Service.this,SimpleService.class));
    }               
};
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can user `AlarmManager` Class for your requirement. Create an alarm  that will awake a `Service` on Specific Timer Interval ( in your case 30-120 seconds ). while awaking destroy the previous running service by calling it `onDestroy()` method.

Comment: Mr.lucifer i am new in AlarmManager.Can you help me regarding this? My code to start and stop the service is given above.

Comment: ok, visit [this](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/10/simple-example-of-alarm-service-using.html) example of Alarm Manager Class